# How to detect that the ipv6 address can be accessed in the android application

Tags: android, ipv6, ipv4

I am in China, ipv6 is being gradually promoted, it is unstable, sometimes it can be accessed, sometimes it is not. My Android app uses java language and requests ipv6 by default. Sometimes the ipv6 of the server is unavailable. I want to switch to ipv4 quickly. Therefore, I want to check whether the ipv6 of the server is accessible before making a network request. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Java guy, but I was able to come up with this.

```
            Process  ping_6_proc = runtime.exec("ping6 your::IPv6::goes::here%your_interface");
            int exit_value = ping_6_proc.waitFor();
```

If `exit_value` is 0, then you had a successful ping. Else, swap over to IPv4.

Comment: These 3 ipv6 addresses, in the ipv6 environment, the ping command of the computer is successful, but they always return 2. in the android app. Why?

Comment: 2 means that its an error. Are you sure that all the arguments are correct within your command string?

Comment: The command is "ping6 2001:da8:8000:1::80%wlan0", is there an error?

Comment: @yangshin, you should only use the Zone ID with a link-local address. "_To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local addresses under prefix fe80::/10.  At the time of writing, this is the only well-defined usage known._"

Comment: @RonMaupin What do you mean？Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using IPv6 if you do not understand that? The `%wlan0` is the Zone ID, and you need to use that for link-local addresses because every interface uses the same network, but global addresses are unique, so you do not use that.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that wlan0 was a placeholder, my apologies. I thought it was clear that choosing an interface was important when doing network activity. I'll edit it real fast!

Comment: @RonMaupinOh, I probably understand. But what should the placeholder be? How should I find this placeholder?

Comment: What placeholder? Either you are using link-local addressing where you use a Zone ID, or you are using global or ULA addressing where you do not use a Zone ID. The specific Zone ID depends on the OS on which it is used, and it is only locally significant to the device, and only used for link-local addressing.